# How should I have one process blocked until another process writes a line to a file?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I have one process(agxp) receiving data and write them a file and another process sending data to the other process.

when agxp starts, it should produce some output right away. I want the main process to block until it sees the first line of output by agxp in the file.

I am checking if the first line has been written to the file by comparing the stat of the file, but they are always the same. So I am stuck in the while loop. Why does this happen?

```
        rvListen_AGX =  "tibrvlisten -service " + agxService  + " -network " + agxNetwork + " -daemon " + domain

        agxf = open(self.AGX_logFileName, 'w')
        agxstat = os.stat(self.AGX_logFileName)
        agxp = subprocess.Popen(rvListen_AGX.split(), stdout = agxf, bufsize=0)


        while os.stat(self.AGX_logFileName) == agxstat:
            print agxstat
            print os.stat(self.AGX_logFileName)
            stxf.flush()
            sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: you could set `stdout=PIPE` and write to `agxf` in the main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait until the child process writes a line to its stdout and to save child's stdout to a file:

```
import shutil
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def copy_and_close(source, destination):
    with source, destination:
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, destination)

agx_cmd = ("tibrvlisten -service {agxService} -network {agxNetwork} "
           "-daemon {domain}".format(**vars())).split()
agx_process = Popen(agx_cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
agx_file = open(self.AGX_logFileName, 'wb')
agx_file.write(agx_process.stdout.readline()) # block until a line is read
Thread(target=copy_and_close, args=[agx_process.stdout, agx_file]).start()
# do other things here..
rc = agx_process.wait()
```

If you don't need to do other things while `agx_process` is running then you could call `copy_and_close()` in the main thread instead.

Comment: I like your idea, but it did not really answer my question. I was asking why my code was stuck in the while loop, rather than how to solve the issue.

Comment: @user1559897: I've answered the "how" from the title. The meaning of the `while`-loop depends on the platform and the filesystem settings e.g., `st_mtime` update may be delayed until the file cache flush.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is process synchronization mechanism. There are multiple primitives which you can use to achieve the same. for example, Lock is used for locking the resource so other process can't access it while it is being used by one process. Similarly, Mutex and semaphore is also serving the same purpose.

I'm providing you one example from python doc which can help you to understand how to implement it.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    print 'hello world', i
    l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

In above example, you can see that there would one mail process which is going to create 10 other process. Here, main process passes lock (created by it) to each process so each process gets the same lock. Now each process would try to acquire lock before doing the actual task. As it is same lock (shared between process), only one process would able to acquire a lock at a time so other process would wait until the first process release the lock.

If your two process are not forked from main process (like totally two different process forked independently ) then you need to implement global shared memory or global mutex or global semaphore.

Comment: it is about child processes created using `multiprocessing`. How does it help with the OP's `subprocess.Popen()`-created child process?